# Partitioning functions into equivalence classes based on running time?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, equivalence-relations

[image]

I'm studying for my midterm and doing some practice problems, and I would be grateful if someone showed how to solve this. From my understanding you have to partition the functions into equivalence classes based on their running time. I am confused on the running time of some functions such as the first function listed. Would the running time be $\Theta(n^2)$ or $\Theta(\frac{n^2}{ln^{2}n})$? Are there 15 equivalence classes?

Comment: I know what $\Theta$ is, but what is $\theta$?

Comment: @Alex I think it is a typo.

Comment: @Alex I fixed it, I typed \theta instead of \Theta. Simple mistake. I apologize.

Comment: @Alex I actually posted a screenshot of the question, so I can't change the theta in the question. I think even the professor or whoever typed it used \theta instead of \Theta haha.

Comment: OK, well, what did you try?